# Zero-to-Hero Tutorial

Tags: nearprotocol

Followed the tutorial and all looked like it was working until I tried to call the function

```
near view crossword.friend.testnet get_puzzle_number
```

and got the error

```
{
  "block_hash": "GxTcbrAXiL3Ad4viEiDM62pVfZaFJzRewtXo8UU2tMi9",
  "block_height": 91856013,
  "error": "wasm execution failed with error: FunctionCallError(MethodResolveError(MethodNotFound))",
  "logs": []
}
```

I used my account rather than 'friend'. Using Windows. Tried from admin console. I can see the transactions in the explorer and error there.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you provide the account ID that the contract is deployed to?

Answer (score 0):

Figured the answer. When compiling it did not highlight that I had not imported the near_sdk::env library in Visual Code. It was missing some extensions. Did it again with that import and VS extensions and it has worked! Sorry to bother.